# How to talk about cooking a dish with multiple items

Tags: simplified-characters, learning

I have been practicing Chinese by writing essays in Chinese. I am starting one on my cooking routines. While I know many food terms, I have never expressed anything beyond basic with respect to food.

I want to say something along the lines of
'I cooked rice with tomato, brocolli, carrots, and peppers.

Would this suffice?
我用番茄，西兰花，胡萝卜和辣椒煮饭。

I want to make it clear that I put these  ingredients together and cooked them.

I feel like 加 would not get the point that all of the things were cooked together.

I am also wondering if I could say,
我跟西兰花，胡萝卜，辣椒，番茄煮饭。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:**

Clarification by the OP

> *I place all the vegetables in a pot with rice and cook them. I think 加 would indicate I add them in after cooking the rice*

In this case, 煮饭 means 'cook rice', 加 would mean you add them into the raw rice when you cook them

The sentence would be

> 我煮饭時会把番茄，西兰花，胡萝卜和辣椒加在米中一起煮 (when I cook rice, I would add tomato, broccoli, carrot, and pepper into the raw rice)

or

> 我会把番茄，西兰花，胡萝卜和辣椒加在煮好的饭中一起再煮 (I would add tomatoes, broccoli, carrots, and peppers into the cooked rice and cook them together

**Previous answer before the Clarification:**

'煮饭' means '**to cook**' in general (饭 here refer to 'meal' ).

Note:

煮饭 (to cook) sounds Cantonese. In Mandarin, the common word for 'to    cook' is 做飯 (cook meal) or 做菜(cook dish),
and 煮饭 would just mean 'cook rice' The reason I presume by 煮饭 you meant 'to cook' because it is wired to add those things in streamed rice

If you meant you are using these ingredients to cook **a dish**. The correct verb phrase is:

我用番茄，西兰花，胡萝卜和辣椒(来煮这道菜) = I use tomatoes, broccoli, carrots, and peppers (**to cook this dish**)

or

(这道菜的材料是)番茄，西兰花，胡萝卜和辣椒 = (**the ingredients of this dish are**) tomatoes, broccoli, carrots, and peppers

> 我跟西兰花，胡萝卜，辣椒，番茄煮饭

It means "我 (and) 胡萝卜，辣椒，番茄煮饭 cook together" (胡萝卜，辣椒，番茄 can't cook). It is nonsensical

To be more precise.

> 我會用番茄，西兰花，胡萝卜和辣椒来煮这道菜 (I **will** cook this dish with tomatoes, broccoli, carrots and peppers)

or

> 我用了番茄，西兰花，胡萝卜和辣椒来煮这道菜 (I used tomatoes, broccoli, carrots, and peppers to cook this dish)

Comment: This is extremely useful. Using 跟 did not seem correct, but I wanted to ensure that 跟 would not function this way. I have one follow up question. What is the purpose of 来 before 煮? I know 来 is used in directional complements, but I am not sure if this is how it is being used here.

Comment: 来 = 'to'  when it is followed by a verb, e.g. 用言語[来]殺人 = use words [to] kill

Comment: Perhaps the ingredients are being directed toward the act of cooking?

Comment: I wish I was on my other account so I could upvote this. Nevertheless, thank you for your careful and well-written response. I see how 来 is being used here. I also found an article detailing this structure you just explained: https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Using_%22lai%22_to_connect_two_verb_phrases

Comment: 我用番茄，西兰花，胡萝卜和辣椒煮饭 would mean you use them regularly as a tool . Similar to 我用鐵鍋煮饭 ( I use an iron wok to cook)

Comment: You say 我用番茄，西兰花，胡萝卜和辣椒煮饭 would express that I often cook with those as my main ingredients? I initially felt this would be interpreted as using them to literally cook the dish as tools, though native speakers may understand what I am saying.

Comment: I should say "我(经常)用番茄，西兰花，胡萝卜和辣椒煮饭" = I (often ) cook with  番茄，西兰花，胡萝卜和辣椒

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably put:

> 我煮饭时会(往米饭里面)放番茄，西兰花，胡萝卜和辣椒。

加 is fine too if what you cook is a type of 饭, not 菜.

In Chinese, if the main ingredient is rice, it's called  xxx饭 such as 卤肉饭，菠萝饭，etc. Otherwise, it's called 菜.

If you want to express that you mixed up every thing including steamed rice, you can say:

> 做"name of your dish" 时(or 我这种饭的做法是)，我会把番茄，西兰花，胡萝卜，辣椒和煮好的米饭放在锅里一块煮。

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112142/discussion-on-answer-by-dan-how-to-talk-about-cooking-a-dish-with-multiple-items).

Comment: @TangHo so you would boil the vegetables with the rice?

Comment: @Michael Ramage. Go to Chat if you want cooking lessons.

Comment: Chinese stack exchange is a magical place

Comment: Yes, the magicians, AKA, Diamond Moderators are the Masters of this Universe.

Comment: I do not think I can go to chat on mobile/: